# Command not found in sh script running from crontab

Tags: python, shell, cron, grafana

I have a sh file that runs: python -m grafana_backup.cli save --config $settings_file.

I run this file from a crontab, runnning the .sh file but I get this error:  python: command not found.

The shell in the crontab is SHELL=/bin/bash and in the .sh file is #!/bin/bash

Comment: Ar you using some kind of virtual environment to run python? If so, you would probably want to source the activate script inside your shell script before invoking python.

Comment: That works! It was that the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

do:

1. 'which python3' - a possible result is /usr/bin/python3
2. Add the result of #1  to the crontab command

A general advice:
Use **full path** to every resource your sh script is using

Comment: As a SHELL variable?

Comment: no. just replace `python` with `/usr/bin/python3` (assuming your python is under usr/bin) in the sh script

Comment: May be more complicated than that if a virtual environment (or conda env) has been activated, which is quite a possible scenario if the path to `python` is something that is not in the default `PATH` in the cron environment.

Comment: the problem I got now is: /usr/bin/python3: No module named grafana_backup seems that using the full path of python change my current path also and I cant access the module